# Cannot render video from BufferedImage using HashMap in Java

Tags: java, jframe, jwt, bufferedimage, gridbaglayout

In my project, I have got a class FramesUtil which contains a set of frames stored in a HashMap -

```
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Frame> frameMap
```

I have another class Arbiter.java that should render video using frames from frameMap.

However, I can only see the first frame when the playVideo() method is being called from Arbiter.java.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FramesUtil.ensureExistence();
        FrameReader reader = new FrameReader();
        reader.readBinary();
        playVideo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Looks like the JFrame is not getting updated with new BufferedImage in the loop during the iteration

Below is my playVideo method from Arbiter.java -

```
    public static void playVideo() {
    BufferedImage img;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    GridBagLayout gLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gLayout);
    JLabel lbIm1;
    for(int i=0; (img=FramesUtil.frameMap.get(i).bufferedImage)!=null; i++) {
        lbIm1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        System.out.println(lbIm1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lbIm1, c);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

PS. I have tried creating new JFrame and GridBagLayout instances inside the for loop

Comment: Start by having a look at [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: I'd also consider a [Producer/Consumer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) probably linked through an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)